# How do I write Regex.Replace() for a specific pattern, such as "12-3456", in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have searched for "C# regex wildcard search" on stackoverflow & on google. Results have not been specific enough for my particular situation...

I am writing a desktop app to search HTM files to replace hard-coded links with relative paths (and also modifying a portion of the link). Currently the files contain the following:

```
http://wwwsc.oldURLnameHere.com/Catalog/detail?itemNo=12-3456" target="_blank" title="12-3456">
```

I need to replace it with the following:

```
"javascript:na_open_window('PRODUCT RESULTS', '/MiniDetailPopup.aspx?itemNo=??-????&externalDetail=false', 200, 200, 750, 250, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"View ??-????\">??-????</a>";
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Results have not been specific enough for my particular situation...* ==> What do you expect? A perfect solution for your problem??? I am quite sure regex is not your solution here, have a look at [ParseQueryString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its always going to be ##-#### format, you could use this pattern:

`@"itemNo=([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})"`

To match anything after itemNo, use this:

`"itemNo=([^\"]*)"`

The result will be in the Group1 of the Match.

P.S. Get RegexBuddy.